# Handling large JSON files in Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, gzip

I have a large JSON file (117 000 000 lines / 2,96 GB) that I need to deserialize into Kotlin objects. The JSON objects consists of 4-6 levels depending on their complexity. What is the best way to deserialize this file effectively?

Worth mentioning is that I'm fetching this file as a GZIP with a GET request to an endpoint.

So for I've tried using GZIPInputStream and creating a BufferedReader from this. I'm using Jackson and the default ObjectMapper for parsing.

Comment: Without too much memory usage?? You do realize that if you actually want to have the data deserialized you very well may end up with more data than the 3GB depending on the actual data? What have you tried, what happened, why do you need to data parsed in its entirety?

Comment: Thank you, I've corrected the question. My problem is it takes way too long to deserialize, and I end up terminating the process. I haven't tried splitting up the JSON into smaller files since I'm not sure how to do that - yet.

Comment: Take a look at event-based https://github.com/markenwerk/java-utils-json-parser

Comment: The "default objectmapper" makes it sound like you are not using the jackson streaming api, which is how you normally parse big files (in your case gzipinputstream as input for jacksons JsonParser, you don't need to handle buffering yourself), since it means you dont need to load everything in memory. That is not necessarily faster though, but performance debugging over stackoverflow is quite impossible, have a look at where the bottleneck is with profiling because it most likely won't be jackson.